# How to manually schedule job from AWS Lambda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rails-activejob, que

I want to replace my cron scheduler. Is there a way to schedule an ActiveJob from a Lambda and Cloudwatch? I'm using the Que gem.

Answer (score 1):

You create a schedule for an AWS Lambda to get triggered AWS Cloudwatch Schedule Expressions

**AWS Doc -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions

To manually trigger your AWS Lambda function you can do it either via the AWS Console, SDK, CLI or use API Gateway, with some security to do so.